# Rails delete associated many to many entry within simple_form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

So I have this in my form:

```
= simple_form for @dvd do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :dvd_genre do |genre_form|
    = genre_form.input :genre
```

The `dvd.rb` relationship with genre:

```
has_many :dvd_genre2title, :foreign_key => 'dogTag'
has_many :dvd_genre, :through => :dvd_genre2title
```

dvd_genre.rb:

```
has_many :genre2title, :foreign_key => 'pId' # junction table
has_many :dvd, :through => :genre2title
```

dvd_genre2title.rb:

```
set_primary_key 'dogTag, pId'
belongs_to :dvd_genre, :foreign_key => 'pId' 
belongs_to :dvd, :foreign_key => 'dogTag'
```

With the above form I get a listing of every genre associated with a specific dvd in an input text field where I can change them. Great.

But what I also want to be able to do is have a little button that deletes the association, preferably via jquery ajax so that we don't have to submit the form to kill the association. It would essentially delete:

```
DELETE FROM dvd_genre2title WHERE dogTag = @dvd.dogTag AND pId = @genre.id
```

Or something to that effect.

I don't know anything about jquery or ajax, but I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished, just don't know how.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: i'm also looking for a way to implement this. did you figure it out?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I sort of gave up and moved on to other, more pressing matters. Still, it would be interesting to get an answer :)